# Wrong message order with kafka-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using [kafka-node](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node) node.js library. I have problem with message order when consuming topic with 250k messages (which where loaded into Kafka in batches of 2000 messages) with fresh start (no offsets in zookeeper). Consumer often does not process messages from offset 0, rather it starts at 4000 or 8000, or so. Also it continuosly processes block of 1000 messages and jumps at later or sooner N*1000 offset. I have tried changed maxTickMessages to 800 and it process block od 800 messages, but it still jumped to N*1000 offset. I could not find missing 200 offsets in debug log. Chaning maxTickMessages or maxNumSegments to very large number did not help.

I was printing current message offset directly in Kafka binary protocol decoder, which should eliminate some of potential async effects. Please see [Offset log](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/files/81878/offsets2.tmp.txt) and used code [kafka-order-test.js](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/files/81875/kafka-order-test.js.txt). I think there is problem in Kafka binary protocol parsing, but I was not able to find problem in it.

Kafka itself should not be a problem as I dumped topic with kafkacat, which mantained correct offset and messages order. I also monitored node.js-Kafka network traffic with Wireshark, and messages were shown in correct order.

Comment: how many partitions do you have? and how is it partitioned? by default the producer distributes messages in a round-robin fashion across partitions and you need to use your own partitioner to define what partition a message lands on. The order is guaranteed within a partition but i don't think it is guaranteed across partitions, so if you need guaranteed order for a key you need to partition by that key to be in the same partition.

Comment: I am not using multiple partitions yet. But this issue affects order in partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by asynchronous nested MessageSet decompression which resulted in out of order message consuming. Kafka returns messages in MessageSet which contains nested compressed MessageSets of 2000 messages (in my testing). Unfortunately decompression was asynchronous without any synchronisation, so messages were processed out of order in batches of max 2000 (depends on maxTickMessages). My [fix](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/pull/301) applies synchronous decompression.

Comment: good to know... i don't use the client for pulling, only to push so i never had this problem.